# Create reference to frequently changed text

Tags: microsoft-word

I have been playing around with Bookmarks and Cross Referencing, but that gets me like 70% of the way.

I have a template document like this:

> Document Number:  NUMBER123 
> Dates: 1 January 2017 to 1 January 2020
>   Fun text: These are the best words and percentages (0%).

And throughout the document want to reference `NUMBER123` and the dates and percentage and other things.

I set `NUMBER123` as a Bookmark, and can successfully reference that anywhere by using a Cross Reference.

Here it is successfully using the references to the Bookmarks:
[image]

My issue is that when I change the bookmarked `NUMBER123` to `NUMBER999`, all of the cross-references change to `NUMBER` when I refresh them.

[image]

How can I set up my references to keep that "area" as the bookmark, not necessarily the text?  Does that make sense?  I am using a template because I have say 20 friends I want to create documents for.  Each will have a unique document number, dates, percentage, etc.  I simply want to be able to reference this in one place and update that everywhere. (Avoiding an Excel or Mail Merge solution, if possible).

Answer (score 1):

In **Word Options** > **Advance** > **Show document content**, select the check box so that bookmarks are visible. My bet is that after you delete the value from inside the bookmark markers, you then end up typing the new value outside them, so that the only text inside the bookmark is **NUMBER** or **1 January 20**, or nothing. By making bookmarks visible, you can make sure that you enter values inside the bookmark markers.